# form_checkbox() cannot input text between produced tag

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I'm using form_helper to create my checkboxes.

```
<?php echo form_checkbox('test','test', $attributes); echo "test"; ?>
```

I always print it below the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" class="checkbox"></input>test
```

How can I make it so it looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" class="checkbox">test</input>
```

Or at least make it so the text "test" is printed beside the checkbox, not on a new line.

Comment: `</input>` isn't a valid closing tag. In not using it, then you won't need  solution for it ;-) so why the question?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I thought so too. i kinda dont know how to make the text side by side to the checkbox. any suggestion? and would css take into consideration?

Comment: input tag doesn't have close tag you already have the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, the class="checkbox" make it so the text go after the checkbox, right below it (new line). I deleted the "checkbox".